# Airflow task argument return from previous task

Tags: python, parallel-processing, airflow

How can I set the function argument to a task that is the return from a previous task / function that was run.  Note that these tasks are defined programmatically, therefore I cannot simply use `xcom_pull(task_id="some_task")` because the tasks are defined in a loop (as shown below):

```
def scrape(site):
    return requests.get(site).content

def echo(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    # how can I use the input from `scrape()` here?

for idx, site in enumerate(sites):
    myop = PythonOperator(task_id='scape_%s' % str(idx), python_callable=scrape, op_args=[site], dag=dag)
    echo_op = PythonOperator(task_id='echo_%s' % str(idx), dag=dag, provide_context=True, python_callable=echo)
    myop.set_downstream(echo_op)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is missing is just passing the required `task_id` so that you will be able to read the xcom value

```
def scrape(site):
    return requests.get(site).content

def echo(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    myop_task_id_value = kwargs['myop_task_id_key']
    x = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=myop_task_id_value) #pulling xcom value of scrape
    print(x)


for idx, site in enumerate(sites):
    myop_task_id = 'scape_%s' % str(idx)
    myop = PythonOperator(task_id= myop_task_id, python_callable=scrape, op_args=[site], dag=dag)
    echo_op = PythonOperator(task_id='echo_%s' % str(idx),
                             dag=dag,
                             provide_context=True,
                             python_callable=echo,
                             op_kwargs={'myop_task_id_key': myop_task_id}
                             )
    myop.set_downstream(echo_op)
```